# which DOCTYPE variation should we use?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which DOCTYPE declaration should we use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000000/which-doctype-declaration-should-we-use)

I have read a number of books on DOCTYPE declaration and the three variations; strict, transitional and frameset.

but is still not able to fully understand their difference and indeed is not sure which variation I should use when creating my website; in particular i don't understand the difference between strict and transitional.

could you please advise me?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: [Which DOCTYPE declaration should we use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000000/which-doctype-declaration-should-we-use)

Comment: Oh, ever so much so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000000/which-doctype-declaration-should-we-use

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 which will be supported in most browsers soon, you just have to declare your doctype as "html". It'll look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```